# File in-place editing with tee behaving differently on different unixes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, tee

A coworker was experimenting with file truncation in a bash shell script: extract two first bytes out of a binary file.

The following worked fine on BSD/OS X ("12" in output) but not on Linux (output was empty):

```
echo 1234 >test
head -c2 test | tee test >/dev/null
```

Changing the `head | tee` part to run in a subshell

```
echo 1234 >test
(head -c2 test | tee test >/dev/null)
```

made it work on Linux as well.

Why?

(Specifically not interested in solutions to the truncating problem but an explanation why the behavior is different on different flavors of operating systems.)

Comment: For a moment, I though you were still running BSD/OS and wondered what X had to do with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tee` opens its arguments for writing, truncating them in the process, but whether `head` or `tee` opens the file first is left to chance. Either behavior is valid; you just shouldn't rely on this mini-script doing anything useful.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thanks. Specifically those linux systems where this was observed were SMP and where this wasn't seen were single-core.